# How to get events of type by reflection ignoring events on parent interfaces

Tags: c#, events, reflection, interface

I have the following code

```
Type type = ...
var events=type.GetEvents(
    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly 
    | BindingFlags.Instance 
    | BindingFlags.Public).ToList();
```

However this is also returning me events declared on
parent interfaces. For example

Both

```
UIElement
ContentElement
```

implement

```
IInputElement
```

which defines the event

```
//
// Summary:
//     Occurs when the mouse pointer moves while the mouse pointer is over the element.
event MouseEventHandler PreviewMouseMove;
```

but the above call to GetEvents with all the binding flags set as above
returns the event for the interface as well as the two concrete classes.

How can I filter out events that are defined on parent interfaces from
GetEvents?

Note that I am generating extensions methods for each event like so

```
public static 
IObservable<EventPattern<MouseButtonEventArgs>> 
PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownObserver(this IInputElement This){
        return Observable
               .FromEventPattern
               <MouseButtonEventHandler, MouseButtonEventArgs>
               ( h => This.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += h
               , h => This.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= h);
}
```

so I only did the root definition of the event not derived virtual or interface implementations.

Comment: What type is returned as you execute `someObject.GetType()`? If it is a concrete class all the events are going to be returned, as they are explicitly implemented. Try to infer the interface you'd like to get and call `GetType()` on the `interface`, not the concrete class.

Comment: Is `type` an interface, or is it a class/struct which implements some interfaces?

Comment: I'm processing all the types in an assembly and for each type extracting the events for code generation purposes. I only want the events declared explicitly on each type or interface not inherited. I'm generating f# style event observables for the whole WPF library bit I end up with redundant code if I generate for both the interface and the concrete class.

Comment: FYI the complete T4 template is here https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/5343651

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example:

```
interface IFace
{
    event EventHandler A;
}

class Base
{
    public virtual event EventHandler B;

    public event EventHandler C;
}

class YourType : Base, IFace
{
    public event EventHandler A;          // implements interface

    public override event EventHandler B; // overrides base class implementation

    public event EventHandler D;          // new event
}
```

which event do you want to see if you use reflection on `typeof(YourType)`?

**ANSWER:**

You can use something like:

```
events.Where(x =>
  x.GetAddMethod().GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType == type
  && !x.GetAddMethod().IsFinal)
  );
```

where `type` is like in your question. The first criterion makes sure it is not an event defined on a parent type. The second criterion makes sure it's not an interface implementation. You might not need the second criterion, depending on your exact setup.

**EDIT to ANSWER**

```
events.Where(x =>{ 
   var addMethod = x.GetAddMethod();
   var basetype = addMethod.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType;
   return basetype == type && (!addMethod.IsFinal || basetype.IsInterface);
})
```

This addition ensures that I get the interfaces as well.

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACH:**

To definitely determine if a member implements some interface or not, one can use this:

```
var interfaceImplementingMethods = new HashSet<MethodInfo>(type.GetInterfaces()
  .SelectMany(i => type.GetInterfaceMap(i).TargetMethods));
var result = events.Where(x => !interfaceImplementingMethods
  .Contains(x.GetAddMethod()));
```

It should work even if the implementing member is declared `virtual` (or `abstract`). This must be combined with `GetBaseDefinition()` if you want to exclude also inherited members, of course.

Comment: Only D is required as I wish only to generate extension methods via t4 for the parent classes implementation.

Comment: See the edit I made to the question with an example of the type of code I'm generating.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing My example `YourType` contains four events, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. I believe the `DeclaredOnly` binding flag only excludes `C`. The other events have implementations in `YourType`.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Just using BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly is not enough. The question is how to achieve what I need?

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Thanks for editing my answer. There's probably still an issue when a clss implements an event from an interface and uses the `virtual` (or `abstract`) keyword on the event.

Comment: probably rare enough that I can skip it for code gen purposes. I've also skipped generic events as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to filter out the events of the interface using linq, like this...

```
Type type = typeof (Bar);
Type interfaceType = typeof (IFoo);
var interfaceEvents = interfaceType.GetEvents(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly 
                                              | BindingFlags.Instance 
                                              | BindingFlags.Public);

var events = type.GetEvents(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly 
                            | BindingFlags.Instance 
                            | BindingFlags.Public);

events = events.Where(e => interfaceEvents.FirstOrDefault(
                ie => ie.Name == e.Name && 
                ie.EventHandlerType == e.EventHandlerType) == null).ToArray();
```

**Edit:**
Events from base classes should not be included in the result from GetEvents method. Here is a method that removes the events of all interfaces the type implements.

**Edit 2:**
This method will also remove overridden base class events:

```
public IEnumerable<EventInfo> GetEventsEx(Type type)
{
    var baseEvents = new List<EventInfo>();

    // Adds Events of interfaces to baseEvents
    foreach (var interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        baseEvents.AddRange(interfaceType.GetEvents(
            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
            | BindingFlags.Instance
            | BindingFlags.Public));
    }

    // Adds Events of base classes to baseEvents
    var baseType = type.BaseType;
    while (baseType != typeof (object))
    {
        baseEvents.AddRange(baseType.GetEvents(
            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
            | BindingFlags.Instance
            | BindingFlags.Public));
        baseType = baseType.BaseType;
    }

    // Get events for type
    var events = type.GetEvents(
        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
        | BindingFlags.Instance
        | BindingFlags.Public);

    // Remove baseEvents and return
    return events.Where(e => baseEvents.FirstOrDefault(
            ie => ie.Name == e.Name &&
            ie.EventHandlerType == e.EventHandlerType) == null);
}
```

**Edit 3:**
New method with the `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` flags removed, this will probably work a little better:

```
public IEnumerable<EventInfo> GetEventsEx(Type type)
{
    var baseEvents = new List<EventInfo>();

    // Adds Events of interfaces to baseEvents
    foreach (var interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        baseEvents.AddRange(interfaceType.GetEvents(
            BindingFlags.Instance
            | BindingFlags.Public));
    }

    // Adds Events of base classes to baseEvents
    var baseType = type.BaseType;
    if (baseType != null && baseType != typeof (object))
    {
        baseEvents.AddRange(baseType.GetEvents(
            BindingFlags.Instance
            | BindingFlags.Public));
    }

    // Get events for type
    var events = type.GetEvents(
        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
        | BindingFlags.Instance
        | BindingFlags.Public);

    // Remove baseEvents and return
    return events.Where(e => baseEvents.FirstOrDefault(
            ie => ie.Name == e.Name &&
            ie.EventHandlerType == e.EventHandlerType) == null);
}
```

Comment: This is a start. But instead of a single interface I want to ignore any events declared on parent classes or interfaces of Bar.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing, I have update my answer. To reflect on your input.

Comment: Cool. I think that you should remove the ``BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`` from the ``Adds Events of base classes to baseEvents`` otherwise you would need to modify the code to be recursive and note that interfaces can implement other interfaces so you might want to drop the ``BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`` in the first loop as well.

Comment: It is easier to check `GetBaseDefinition`. See my edited answer.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing, Thanks, the base classes loop is recursive but your right I removed `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` and created a new method.

Comment: @JensGranlund good work. However I've just looked at the other answer that Jeppe made and it's pretty short and sweet and if it works is the one I'll go for. Thanks for the work however :)

Comment: @bradgonesurfing, I like his answer better too.