# Show event history of some object

Tags: c#, .net, events

Imagine that I have have `Class1 obj1 = new Class1()`. Class1 has many different events. I want to know what event and when does it happened, but I don't want to create event handler for every event of this object. How can I do it?

Example output that I want to see:

```
13:04:29 Obj1.OnEvent1
13:04:31 Obj1.OnEvent2
13:04:32 Obj1.OnEvent3
13:04:35 Obj1.OnEvent2
......................
```

P.S.: I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

Comment: In what context do you want to know?  During execution? As a log that's persisted?  When there's an issue?

Comment: its [possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2), but its very complicated, because each event can be different (other parameters, etc).

Comment: Have you looked at using reflection to query the object for it's events, attach to them and log as you please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895091/how-to-get-events-of-type-by-reflection-ignoring-events-on-parent-interfaces

Answer (score 1):

You have to instrument your code using, for example, the [Semantic Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn440729.aspx).

If you follow the established practice of having a `protected virtual` `OnEvent` method the fires the `*Event*` event, you'll find out the the actual event is the `OnEvent` method is in fact the real event and the `*Event*` .NET event is just a notification others can subscribe to. And you want to log events and not event subscriptions.

You can have something that subscribes to the events and log it, but you'll also soon find out that you'll want to log more than those events.

Answer (score 0):

If the delegate types of your eventhandler are uniform you can iterate over the events obtained from the type and attach your logging logic to the event. I use a logger class with methods for Subscibe and Unsubscribe (not implemented here)

#### Logger

```
public class EventLogger
{   
    public void Subscribe<T>(T obj)
    {
        // get the type to iterate over the EventInfo's
        var type = typeof (T);
        foreach (var eve in type.GetEvents())
        {
            EventInfo info = eve;
            // attach our logging logic 
            eve.AddEventHandler(obj, 
                new EventHandler((sender, args) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "{0} {1}.{2}", 
                            DateTime.Now, 
                            obj,
                            info.Name);
                    }));
        }
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
        //todo unsubscribe
    }

}
```

#### Demo Class

```
public class Class1
{
    // public delegate void MyDelegate(string key, DateTime date, int value);

    public event EventHandler Foo;
    public event EventHandler Bar;
    // public event MyDelegate Cancel;

    public void Raise()
    {
        this.Bar(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        // this.Cancel(null, DateTime.Now, 4);
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
var c = new Class1();
c.Bar += (sender, eventArgs) => { Console.WriteLine("bar"); };

// have our logger ready
var logger = new EventLogger();
// attach logging to a specific instance
logger.Subscribe(c);

// raise our events
c.Raise();
```

Notice that we only can handle delegates of the type EventHandler. (I commented the delegate MyDelegate because that would break this simple implementation). If you have events that use different delegates you either need to build a switch statement in the `Subscribe` method to handle each differen type or implement a method to generate a dynamic assembly that can handle the delegate as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).